# Convergence almost surely and B-C lemmas

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

[image]

Showing the expectation is straightforward.

I am not sure how to use the Borel-Cantelli lemmas to show the almost surely part.

Comment: Hint: Show that $X_n=-1$ for every $n$ large enough, that is, the random set $\{n\mid X_n\ne-1\}$ is finite, almost surely.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not see how to use your comment. Surely $X_n$ for very large $n$ could still equal $n^2-1$ with (albeit very small) probability $1/n^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Borel–Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) tells us that since
$$ \sum_n P(X_n \not = -1) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} < \infty$$
then the probability of $X_n \not = -1$ occurring for infinitely many $n$ is $0$.
Thus $P(X_n=-1 \text{ for all but finite number of $n$})=1$ and

$$P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}\rightarrow-1)=1$$

Comment: "This means that"... not quite this.

Comment: @Did: is it better now? Thanks.

Comment: Definitely. $ $